# How can I connect two linux machines to transfer files between them

Tags: linux, yum

1. My host OS is Windows 10, I can connect to a Linux CentOS machine that has no internet access
2. I have a virtual machine on Windows 10 that has installed Linux CentOS.
3. I have on the virtual machine linux a private yum repository and I would like to make the Linux machine without internet access to connect to the virtual machine linux and download from the yum repository ?

How can I do this ?

Comment: If you use VMware Workstation to run your CentOS VM, you need to configure bridged networking (https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/14.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-3D56BF46-5980-48F1-AB47-CC0CDB814D8B.html) so that CentOS VM appears as an additional computer on the network. This will let the physical CentOS system use the VM's resources. If the built-in firewall is running on the CentOS VM, you may need to configure the firewall to allow access to port 80 or 443, or shut it down with `sudo systemctl stop firewalld`.

Comment: How can I find out the ip address of the Linux that is installed on the virtual machine ? So i can use the ip address to ping it from the other Linux machine in the network to see it they can see each other

Comment: To find out which IP address is configured on CentOS, regardless of whether it is a VM or a physical system, use the `ip addr` command. Note that ICMP packets may be blocked and `ping` may not work if the built-in firewall is running on the CentOS VM,, so I recommend that you stop the firewall first with `sudo systemctl stop firewalld`, or test the port directly, for example with `telnet <IP address of CentOS VM> 80` (if the connection suceeds, exit `telnet` with `Control-]`) or `nc -v <IP address of CentOS VM> 80` (if the connection succeeds, you can exit `nc` with `Control-C`).

Answer (score 0):

If:

- you can ssh from your centos-vm into your centos-host
- from centos-host you can access centos-vm

then you could do something like:

```
ssh -R13128:<centos-vm-ip>:3128 root@centos-host
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:13128
# add your repository with url pointing to centos-vm
yum install
```